# MULE Esb xml to Object transformer

Tags: mule, esb

I am trying to utilize the xml to object transformer in mule while transfroming an xml payload to a Java Bean (Customer). Here is my simple flow. The exception I am seeing is below

```
Exception stack is:
1. CUSTOMER (com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException)
  com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper:56 (null)
2. CUSTOMER (com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
  org.mule.module.xml.transformer.XmlToObject:76 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: CUSTOMER
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:56)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

**FLOW**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd">
    <flow name="alternateFlow1" doc:name="alternateFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8999" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="www.thomas-bayer.com" port="80" path="sqlrest/CUSTOMER/3/" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <mulexml:xml-to-object-transformer returnClass="com.abc.dto.CUSTOMER" doc:name="XML to Object"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

**XML:**

```
<CUSTOMER xmlns:xlink="w3.org/1999/xlink">
 ;
 <ID>4</ID>
 <FIRSTNAME>Sylvia</FIRSTNAME>
 <LASTNAME>Ringer</LASTNAME>
 <STREET>365 College Av.</STREET>
 <CITY>Dallas</CITY>
</CUSTOMER>
```

Comment: Show the XML payload as well.

Comment: <CUSTOMER xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<ID>4</ID>
<FIRSTNAME>Sylvia</FIRSTNAME>
<LASTNAME>Ringer</LASTNAME>
<STREET>365 College Av.</STREET>
<CITY>Dallas</CITY>
</CUSTOMER>

Comment: Not in comment please :( Edited your question for you.

Comment: The `;` is strange in this XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an alias in the `mulexml:xml-to-object-transformer`:

```
<mulexml:alias name="CUSTOMER" class="com.abc.dto.CUSTOMER" />
```

Also there's no reason to go all caps with the class name so rename your class and alias it:

```
<mulexml:alias name="CUSTOMER" class="com.abc.dto.Customer" />
```

Comment: New Exception Could not find a transformer to transform "SimpleDataType{type=org.hhmi.dto.Customer, mimeType='application/xml'}" to "SimpleDataType{type=org.mule.api.transport.OutputHandler, mimeType='*/*'}".

Comment: I guess that's because the `http:inbound-endpoint` is `request-response` and Mule doesn't know how to transform the `org.hhmi.dto.Customer` object into a valid HTTP response. What do you intend to return to the caller?

Comment: Thanks David i was just experimenting for an upcoming project.